# Check if executable may try to connect to the internet

Tags: python, linux, antivirus

I'm writing a simple anti-malware for my end of year school project. I've got some basics nailed down but I would like to add a feature that checks an executable to see if it may attempt to connect to the internet.

Which way should I approach this? Looking at the hex of a program written in C I can see that the libraries included are shown in plain text. Should I look for librairies like socket.h ? Is this reliable?

Note that I'm a second year ethical hacking student so I'm not expected to produce something that rivals professional AV software.

Also I'm programming my AV in Python and demonstrating it under Linux.

Comment: You do have socket in python, but it's a pain in ... leg to work directly with. Is not more easy to put a url request in a function and check for result/error ? I think urlopen could report a fail to connect after a number of seconds

Comment: I don't think looking for strings is reliable because functions could be imported from a DLL by ordinal, not necesarly by name (at least under Windows). Short answer is, there is no easy way to check if a program connects to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to see if `socket.h` was included, and the relevant functions are in libc, so they will always be available to the application. I would try to see if the application actually calls those functions.

A simple way (in shell) to check if an executable directly calls socket functions:

```
objdump -D `which wget` | grep '<\(accept\|bind\|connect\|getpeername\|getsockname\|getsockopt\|listen\|recv\|recvfrom\|recvmsg\|send\|sendmsg\|sendto\|setsockopt\|shutdown\|socket\|socketpair\)@'
```

`objdump -D` disassembles the executable (including data sections, in case some malicious executable is using some trickery), then `grep` checks for any calls to the libc functions prototyped in `socket.h`.

But that only works if the executable itself directly calls the socket functions, which is not always the case. Replace `wget` with `curl` and you'll get no results. The reason is that `curl`'s network functionality is all within `libcurl`.

So, next step: look at the libraries.

```
ldd `which curl`
```

Actually, this could be your first step even. If the executable is linked to some obvious networking libraries (i.e. `libssl.so.1.0.0`), you could stop here. But assuming it isn't, you now have the list of dynamic libraries loaded by the executable. You can use `objdump -D` on those as well. And disassembling `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4` shows that the library does indeed call the socket functions.

Hopefully this gives you a decent starting point. Besides the tediousness (though that's mitigated by the fact that you're going to write code to do this for you), there is also the issue that ANY external function named the same as the socket functions will show up using my command line. That shouldn't be a big deal if you're ok with erring on the side of false-positives, but there might be a better way to check the functions.

EDIT: This may not work on all binaries. `grep` finds those function names directly in the executable, which I didn't expect on the distributed `wget` and `curl` in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, pardon my ignorance but would your method only work with executables written in C?

Comment: Yes. It may work with other languages which compile to machine code, but different methods will be necessary for interpreted/byte-code languages. For example, with Python you could check for any relevant imports in .py files (i.e. `socket`, `urllib`, etc) and use the Python decompiler for `.pyc`/`.pyo` files - but you also need to do a C-style check on any `.so` files if they exist (in case someone creates a C extension to use socket functions directly in order to bypass those imports).

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is a form of Signature Scanning.

You will compare code to known malicious code signatures and see if the code is included in the rogue application.

Say this is a line of code that is known as malicious and compiles to a certain signature that is also know:

```
Send IP address to hacker
```

HEX OF

```
 00105e0 e6b0 343b 9c74 0804 e7bc 0804 e7d5 0804
 00105f0 e7e4 0804 e6b0 0804 e7f0 0804 e7ff 0804
 0010600 e80b 0804 e81a 0804 e6b0 0804 e6b0 0804
```

Your program could then search the hex of files in an attempt to locate known malicious signatures.

Something more likely you could accomplish in a short amount of time is what is called:

Behavioral Blocking

Think of things a virus or malicious code might try to do to your system, and watch for it.
The previous code pretends to connect out and send an IP address somewhere.
Much like a firewall, you can watch for the attempted connection OUT to be established and alert the user.

You can also monitor for files that are NOT normally modified or accessed to have such happen.